# Datepicker displays only the previous date, not the most recently selected date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I'm using `React`, and have components in `DatePicker`.

Currently, when I select a date in DatePicker I can only get the previously selected date to print in console, so when I first access the webpage it always tells me the default date of January 1st, 2021 instead of the date I selected.

How can I make datepicker display the selected date and not the preivously selected one?

my code:

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());

const handleChange = date => {
    const valueOfInput = date;
    console.log(valueOfInput)
  };

<div> 
          From
          <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={(v => setStartDate(v))} dateFormat="yyyy-MM" showMonthYearPicker showFullMonthYearPicker showTwoColumnMonthYearPicker todayButton="Today" maxDate={new Date()} placeholderText='Results from:' defaultDate={''}/>
          To
          <DatePicker selected={endDate} onChange={(v => setEndDate(v))} dateFormat="yyyy-MM" showMonthYearPicker showFullMonthYearPicker showTwoColumnMonthYearPicker todayButton="Today" maxDate={new Date()} placeholderText='Results to:' defaultDate={''}/>
      </div>
```

Selecting a date such as february 2011, currently yeilds:
`Fri Jan 01 2021 14:49:33 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

but when I click on that it should yield:
`Fri Feb 01 2011 14:49:33 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we are missing some information, you Datepicker components reference a startDate var I don't see defined anywhere.

But to answer your question.

What happens if you render only one Datepicker component? Maybe you the log of 1 of the components instead of the other one.

Comment: I edited the original code, to include the start that has the startDate parameter. I am not very good with react so excuse any issues. Thank you!

Comment: Forgive the formatting, I am on mobile. Perhaps a small rewrite could solve it: ` onChange={(v => setStartdate(v))} ` This is calls the setStartdate method (the setter for your state) with the selected value. Do keep me updated, maybe I can try something else instead when I'm not on mobile.

Comment: Do keep in mind that both of your components reference the same state at the moment, perhaps removing one for the time being could give you some insight

Comment: I will update the changes I've made, I appreciate your feedback, nothing is erroring out at the moment, but I am not sure How I can check to make sure that my values are actaully updating. If not using a callback function, how can I log that value to check for a change?

Comment: You are passing the state value as selected attribute to the datepicker, so the datepicker should show the correct value. You can also change the onChange value to {console.log(v) || setStartdate(v)}

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!